# Windows Form Custom Control key down event not working properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, input, picturebox

I have a small problem, i am trying to read key inputs in c#, the keys A and D work but Z, Space and C don't? Heres my code:

```
private async void RaceSelection_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (movable == true)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                Character.Left -= 3;
                playerpos = Character.Location;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                Character.Left += 3;
                playerpos = Character.Location;
                if (Character.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox6.Bounds))
                {
                    if (Character.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox4.Bounds))
                    {
                        pictureBox4.Location = new Point(999999, 9999999);
                        Character.Top += 9;
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                        Character.Top += 9;
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                        Character.Top += 9;
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                        Character.Top += 9;
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                        Character.Top += 9;
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                        Character.Top += 9;
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                        Character.Top += 5;
                        this.Controls.Clear();
                        this.Controls.Add(GapFiller1);

                        dungeonone();

                    }
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
                {
                    Character.Top -= 25;
                    await Task.Delay(125);
                    Character.Top += 25;
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
                {
                    if (Character.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox5.Bounds))
                    {
                        TownOne();
                    }
                }

                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Z)
                {
                    if (Character.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox6.Bounds))
                    {

                        if (EntityVar.DraugarHealth == 1)
                        {
                            Engine.EntityVar.Draugartakesdamage = false;

                            this.Controls.Remove(pictureBox6);
                            LastKill = "Draugar";
                            label3.Text = "Well Done! but what is that ladder over there???";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Engine.EntityVar.DraugarHealth -= 1;
                            if (Engine.EntityVar.Draugartakesdamage == true)
                            {
                                this.Controls.Add(HitMarker);
                                HitMarker.BringToFront();
                                await Task.Delay(250);
                                this.Controls.Remove(HitMarker);
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong??? I am making a game by the way, I am very aware that im not doing it the best way but oh well thats how im doing it :D, anyway if you know why it doesn't work I would be very gratefull.

Comment: How are you sure that it doesn't work ? can you describe your test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you simply bracket'd your code wrong. In your given code, the Z, C, and Space key handlers are actually *inside* the D handler. I assume you don't want this logic to exist, so move them outside of the D handler and it will fix your problem.

Also, use a switch or else if blocks for this :)